# Calling an unmanaged dll with unknown parameters at run time in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, unmanaged

I need to call a function from an unmanaged dll and I don't know which function or what the parameters will be until run-time. Trust me, there is no way for me to know it at compile-time.

Is there anyway to do this in C#?

- Using DLLImport is out as I don't know what the function will be.
- I've looked at __arglist but it's undocumented and still seems to require me to know the arguments at compile-time

Other than using a different language that allows me to write some inline assembly, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: When do you know it ? Do have string informations with the name at runtime ? Finally you have to generate a call.

Comment: At run-time I have all the information I need: the name/location of the dll, name of the function, name and types of the parameters, and the calling convention.

Comment: You could use CodeDOM or Reflection.Emit to dynamically generate an assembly/type with a method that has the proper binding.

Comment: While CodeDOM is not quite what I need (it generates code files, not an actual working run-time functions). Reflection.Emit seems to be exactly right for this. Still you don't explain how to use it with unmanaged Dll functions, so it's not quite an answer, but it comes close. I think I can figure out the rest of it myself, and if I do, I'll post it here.